# Ayuda en Java, tengo problemas al imprimir un Array String []

Tags: java, string

Hola quiero imprimir una lista de arrayList que posee nombre de un documento, su direccion, su valor y un array String [] de quienes votaron por ese documento pero me imprime con ciertos objetos y con otros no.
Este es mi main

```
package PackPiezas;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class EjecutorMain {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        ArrayList <Personas> listPersona=new ArrayList();
        String namePer []= {"javier", "jesus", "ramses", "sol", "antonieta",
                            "flor", "jorge", "mariangel","manuel", "marlyn",
                            "maria", "nenina", "diana", "yoser", "weber",
                            "jose andres", "simon", "rosimar", "andres", "carlos luis"};
        BusqArc p=new BusqArc();
        p.StartList();//Aqui creo la lista de documentos, solo obtiene documentos de una carpeta del equipo
        MetodosListCanc p1=new MetodosListCanc(p.listCanc);

        CrearPer(listPersona, namePer,p,p1);

        System.out.println("*********************************************************");

        MetodosListCanc.OrdXValue(p.listCanc);

        for(int i=0; i<p.listCanc.size();i++){
            MetodosListCanc.impObj(p.listCanc.get(i)); //Aqui mando a imprimir
        }
    }

    private static void CrearPer(ArrayList <Personas> listPersona, String [] namePer, BusqArc sp,MetodosListCanc pd){

        for(int i=0; i<20;i++){
            Personas sd=new Personas(namePer[i]);
            listPersona.add(sd);
        } 
        VotoPer(listPersona,sp,pd);// este metodo realiza una especie de votacion aleatoria
    }

    private static void VotoPer(ArrayList <Personas> lista, BusqArc sp, MetodosListCanc pd){
        int j=0;
        while(j<20){
            int i=0;
            while(i<3){
                int num=(int) (Math.random() * sp.listCanc.size()-1) + 0;
                if(!DocVot(lista.get(j).getNameArc(), (String) sp.listCanc.get(num).getName())){
                    pd.sumValue(num, lista.get(j));
                    i++;
                }
            }
            j++;
        }
    }

    private static boolean DocVot(String [] numArc, String arc){
        boolean existe=false;
        for(int i=0; i<3;i++){
            if(numArc[i]==arc){
                existe=true;
            }
        }
        return existe;
    }
}
```

Aca es donde tengo el metodo

```
     package PackPiezas;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class MetodosListCanc {


  ArrayList <InfCanc> list;

  public MetodosListCanc(ArrayList<InfCanc> list){
      this.list=list;
  }

public void sumValue(int i, Personas j){
    list.get(i).setVal(list.get(i).getVal()+1);
    String DDoc []=j.getNameArc();
    //System.out.println("1)"+Arrays.toString(DDoc));
    boolean ing=false;
    for(int h=0; h<3;h++){
        if(DDoc[h]==null && ing==false){
            DDoc[h]=(String) list.get(i).getName();
            ing=true;
        }
    }
    j.setNameArc(DDoc);

    boolean ingV=false;
    String VVot []=list.get(i).getVotantes();
    for(int h=0; h<20;h++){
        if(VVot[h]==null && ingV==false){
            VVot[h]=j.getName();
            ingV=true;
        }
    }
    list.get(i).setVotantes(VVot);
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.get(i).getVotantes())); Aqui comprobe que se este guardando el String [] en el objeto y si lo hace pero no entiendo sigue ocurriendo lo mismo
}

public static void OrdXValue(ArrayList <InfCanc> list){
    int tamA=list.size();
    int aux,j;
    for(int i=0;i<tamA;i++){
        j=i;
        aux=list.get(i).getVal();
        //System.out.println("valor de aux= "+aux+" Vuelta ="+i);
        InfCanc obAux=new InfCanc(list.get(i));
        while(j>0 && list.get(j-1)!=null && aux<list.get(j-1).getVal()){
            list.remove(j);
            list.add(j-1, obAux);
            j--;
        }
        //System.out.println("valor de j="+j);  
    }
}
public static void impObj(InfCanc i){
    System.out.println(i.getName());
    System.out.println(i.getLoc());
    System.out.println(i.getVal());
    System.out.println("Votantes: [");
    String sl []=i.getVotantes();
    for(int j=0; j<20;j++){
        System.out.print(sl[j]+", ");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
    System.out.println("------------");
}
/*public static void impObj(int i){
    System.out.println(list.get(i).getName());
    System.out.println(list.get(i).getLoc());
    System.out.println(list.get(i).getVal());
    System.out.println("Votantes: "+Arrays.toString(list.get(i).getVotantes()));
    System.out.println("------------");
}*/}
```

Esta es mi salida, si observan algunos tiene su voto pero no registra quien voto

```
doc.pdf
C:\Users\Javier Marín\Documents
2
Votantes: [
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ]
------------
Reglamento Trab de Grado Pregr junio 2016.pdf
C:\Users\Javier Marín\Documents
2
Votantes: [
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ]
------------
Trabajo de pasantias - Corfo.pdf
C:\Users\Javier Marín\Documents
2
Votantes: [
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ]
------------
Antecentes penales Apostillados - Jose Gregorio Silva Guedez.PDF
C:\Users\Javier Marín\Documents
3
Votantes: [
ramses, sol, nenina, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ]
------------
Apostilla del titulo - Jose Gregorio Silva Guedez.PDF
C:\Users\Javier Marín\Documents
3
Votantes: [
antonieta, diana, simon, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ]
------------
EJEMPLO INFORME DE PASANTIAS.pdf
C:\Users\Javier Marín\Documents
3
Votantes: [
antonieta, flor, rosimar, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ]
------------
Trabajo de Pasantias - Corfo firmado.pdf
C:\Users\Javier Marín\Documents
3
Votantes: [
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ]
------------
escanear0001 (2).pdf
C:\Users\Javier Marín\Documents
4
Votantes: [
jorge, mariangel, marlyn, weber, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ]
------------
escanear0001 (3).pdf
C:\Users\Javier Marín\Documents
4
Votantes: [
javier, weber, jose andres, carlos luis, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ]
------------
escanear0001.pdf
C:\Users\Javier Marín\Documents
4
Votantes: [
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ]
------------
Foto - Jose Gregorio Silva Guedez.PDF
C:\Users\Javier Marín\Documents
4
Votantes: [
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ]
------------
normas_t_grado2016.pdf
C:\Users\Javier Marín\Documents
4
Votantes: [
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ]
------------
Partida de Nacimiento - Jose Gregorio Silva Guedez.PDF
C:\Users\Javier Marín\Documents
4 /*aca se muestra el numero de votos, y abajo debe mostrar quienes votaron*/
Votantes: [
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ]
------------
escanear0001 (4).pdf
C:\Users\Javier Marín\Documents
5
Votantes: [
jesus, ramses, mariangel, manuel, simon, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ]
------------
Pasaporte - Jose Gregorio Silva Guedez.PDF
C:\Users\Javier Marín\Documents
5
Votantes: [
javier, nenina, weber, jose andres, andres, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ]
------------
```

Hay algunos documentos donde no se registran los votos y otros documentos donde si se registran los votos, no entiendo ya intenten hacerlo de distintas formas, primero le envie la lista de arraylist, despues le envie el objeto y despues le envie solo la posicion del documento que deseo que imprima y aun asi me da el mismo resultado el String[] sale nulo y otro si sale con sus votantes, cualquier opinión seria de ayuda.

Comment: Curioso, acabo de ver otra pregunta similar, pero solo con el imprimir, donde asumí que era que no querías imprimir los null, ahora me doy cuenta con todo el código que tu problema no es al imprimir, es al generar el String[ ] que contiene los nombres.

Comment: si, la otra pregunta era la misma, y si tengo el problema de imprimir el String[]

Comment: A mi parecer no es el imprimir, sino la carga de datos sobre ese array que está dejando valores en null, o bueno, que no está setendo los valores.